# How to play remote mp4 file through HTTP on Android TV

Tags: browser, networking, video, android-tv, video-streaming

This is something that I've been able to do easily on a PC or an Android smartphone, but there seems to be something in Android TV (at least in version 9) that prevents it. I have video files in a remote computer and they are available for download through a HTTP server.

On the PC or the Android smartphone I just enter the full URL (http://.../files/video.mp4) in a web browser or in VLC player, it buffers for a few seconds and then starts playing.

But on Android TV this can only be used with small files. For bigger ones, it seems to be trying to download them completely (I see that by looking at the upload data rate on the server network interface). In a local network I would Chromecast it to the TV but they are in different networks.

I tried:

- both with the builtin web browser and with apps like VLC and MX Player, all of them try to download the whole file first
- Different file formats, including MP4 with H264+AAC which I know that the builtin web browser can play
- Different HTTP server programs
- HTTP and HTTPS
- serving the files with MIME types video/mp4 and application/octet-stream

Is there anything more that I can try or is this impossible to do on Android TV?

**EDIT**:
This is an example request from the TV web browser:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.133:9991
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Andr0id 9; TPM191E) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2207.0 OMI/4.20.3.56.Typhoon.59 Model/Philips-MT5599
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-ES,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

Comment: What HTTP server is used? May be it lacks a feature (like chunking ) that is expected by the player on AndroidTV?

Comment: @Robert Couldn't remember exactly but I tried a few of them again and finally this server worked perfect with the default web browser: `npm install http-server -g && http-server . `